# Using an array of records in Qsort, in c or c++

Tags: c++, qsort

lastname is a field in the record, EmployeeRecord as defined in record.h, I am trying to use 
Qsort to sort the string in employee[emptotal].lastname.

```
#include "./record.h"

void externalSort(EmployeeRecord *lastname,int empcount,int emptotal)
{
empcount = 0;
emptotal = 5;
EmployeeRecord employee[emptotal];
int left=empcount,
right=emptotal;
EmployeeRecord pivot[].lastname = employee[(empcount+emptotal)/2].lastname;

  while (left < right) {
// find left candidate
  while (&employee[left].lastname  < &pivot[(empcount+emptotal)/2].lastname) left++; 
// find right candidate 
  while (&employee[right].lastname > &pivot[(empcount+emptotal)/2].lastname) right--; 
  if (left <= right) {
    EmployeeRecord &temp.lastname = &employee[left].lastname;
    &employee[left].lastname = &employee[right].lastname;
    &employee[right].lastname = &temp.lastname;
    left++;
right--;
  } 
} // while left < right
if (empcount < right) externalSort(char *lastname,empcount,right);
if (left < emptotal) externalSort(char *lastname,left,emptotal);

}
```

I'm sorry there have been so many different changes, I'm at a loss as to the correct way to do the first few lines, My main issue is with the declaration line, EmployeeRecord pivot[].lastname = employee[(empcount+emptotal)/2].lastname;
once I know how to declare pivot correctly, then I'll know how to assign the sort correctly, I believe.

(also it will help with assigning temp.)

(record.h if it helps)

```
typedef char STR9[9+1];
typedef char STR7[7+1];
typedef char STR16[16+1];
typedef struct EmployeeRecord
{
   STR9 lastname;
   STR7 firstname;
   STR16 fullname;   
   float hours, 
         overhours,
         pay_rate, 
         defered, 
         gross, 
         fedtax, 
         statetax, 
         ssitax, 
         netpay;
} EmployeeRecord;
```

Comment: You should use `strcmp(employee[left].lastname, pivot[(empcount+emptotal)/2].lastname) < 0` instead of `&employee[left].lastname < &pivot[(empcount+emptotal)/2].lastname`

Comment: so not my original question, but thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there lot of errors in your code.

You definitely need to look at those.

And appears that you're sorting a record based on `lastname`

Why don't you use `qsort` ?

Something like this:

```
const int no_of_employee =100;

EmployeeRecord *ER[no_of_employee];

static int compare(const void *e1, const void *e2)
{
    EmployeeRecord *tmp1 =*(EmployeeRecord **)e1;
    EmployeeRecord *tmp2 =*(EmployeeRecord **)e2;
    return strcmp( tmp1->lastname,tmp2->lastname);
}


qsort (ER, no_of_employee, sizeof(EmployeeRecord *), compare);
```

Also, I'd suggest to use STL to make it more simpler.

Its pretty hard to point out and every bug in your code, analyse your bugs with co-relating with following code (approx. similar to your code)

```
void swap(EmployeeRecord *e1, EmployeeRecord *e2)
{
    EmployeeRecord tmp ;
    tmp = *e1;
    *e1 = *e2;
    *e2 = tmp;
}

void externalSort(EmployeeRecord employee[], int start, int end){
    if(start < end){
        int left=start+1, right=end;
        EmployeeRecord pivot = employee[start];
        while(left<right){
            if(strcmp(employee[left].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0)
                left++;

            else if(strcmp(employee[right].lastname, pivot.lastname) > 0)
                right--;
            else
                swap(&employee[left],&employee[right]);
        }
        if(strcmp(employee[left].lastname, pivot.lastname) < 0){
            swap(&employee[left],&employee[start]);
            left--;
        }
        else{
            left--;
            swap(&employee[left],&employee[start]);
        }
        externalSort(employee, start, left);
        externalSort(employee, right, end);
    }
}

   // externalSort(employee, 0, emptotal);
```

Comment: I need to know Qsort works, because I can use the "easy" version. This is why I don't use qsort. I need to learn, the correct way to setup pivot. Thank you very much though, and I will use this in the future.